# How do I fill in blank cells?

Tags: r

I have a csv file where some of the entries in some columns are blank. I have corresponding columns which have data which could be used to fill in the blank fields. Let's say one of the columns with blanks is called Old Info, and one of the columns with replacement information is called New Info. I don't want to replace Old Info with the New Info, I only want to fill in blanks in Old Info with data from New Info. Data would come from the same row, i.e. if Old Info Row 1 is blank, then information would be taken from New Info Row 1.

Additionally, I have a secondary column that also has replacement information, which could be called Secondary Replacement Info. If Old Info Row 1 is blank, and so is New Info Row 1, then I would want to replace Old Info Row 1 with Secondary Replacement Info Row 1. Here's some example data:

```
    Old Info     New Info   Secondary Replacement Info
1      Carl         Carl               Carl
2                   Diana              Diana
3      Jeremy       Jeremy             Jeremy
4                                      Jack
```

And here's the desired outcome:

```
    Old Info     New Info   Secondary Replacement Info
1      Carl         Carl               Carl
2      Diana        Diana              Diana
3      Jeremy       Jeremy             Jeremy
4      Jack                            Jack
```

So as you can see, the blanks in Old Info have been filled in. Row 2 was filled in by New Info, but Row 4 was filled in by Secondary Replacement Info, as New Info also had a blank. How would I write a function to accomplish all of this?

Comment: and you don´t need to fill the last column?

Comment: Ok I just added some sample data and outcome to illustrate what I'm going for.

Comment: Try `df1[,1][df1[,1]==''] <- df1[,2][df1[,1]==''];df1[,1][df1[,1]==''] <- df1[,3][df1[,1]=='']`  If the secondary replacement info column contain all the values, then you may need only a single replacement i.e. the 2nd one.

Comment: @akrun I understand how df and the df1 argument work, but I'm trying to piece that together into a function that just allows me to input the column which has blanks, the primary replacement data column, and the secondary replacement data column, and output a fully-filled out column with no blanks. How would I make it so that if any row in Old Info is blank, it will be replaced by the same row in one of the replacement columns?

Comment: Suppose if the 2nd and 3rd columns are not blank for a row that is blank for the 1st column and the values are not the same (in the example it seems both columns have the same values always), then I guess you want to replace the blank with value from the 2nd column instead of the third?

Comment: Definitely. The value in the 2nd column is more important than anything in the 3rd. The value in the 3rd would only be used if the row is blank in the 1st and 2nd columns.

Comment: @xxxRxxx I got busy with something else.  Looks like Roland posted with some function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#import your data
#don't forget to set stringsAsFactors = FALSE
DF <- read.csv(text = "Old Info,New Info,Secondary Replacement Info
1,Carl,Carl,Carl
2,,Diana,Diana
3,Jeremy,Jeremy,Jeremy
4,,,Jack", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#a little function
fun <- function(x, y, z) {
  y[y == ""] <- z[y == ""] #substitute missings in y with values from z
  x[x == ""] <- y[x == ""] #substitute missings in x with values from y
  x #return
}

DF <- within(DF, Old.Info <- fun(Old.Info, New.Info, Secondary.Replacement.Info))
#  Old.Info New.Info Secondary.Replacement.Info
#1     Carl     Carl                       Carl
#2    Diana    Diana                      Diana
#3   Jeremy   Jeremy                     Jeremy
#4     Jack                                Jack
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a for loop, which is probably not that efficient, but it is a function and it should get the job done. I'm inputting the file that I used for input, which is a csv (like your text, but unlike your example input), so please let me know if I should switch that.

```
#read in csv file
data = read.csv("/Users/amckenz/Documents/github/R-plots/SO/replace_data.txt", fill = T, na.strings = "")

replace_missing_info <- function(data_df){

    for(i in 1:nrow(data_df)){
        print(i)
        if(is.na(data_df[i, 1])){
            if(!is.na(data_df[i, 2])){
                data_df[i, 1] = data_df[i, 2]
            } else if(!is.na(data_df[i, 3])){
                data_df[i, 1] = data_df[i, 3]
            }
        }
    }

    return(data_df)

}

updated_data = replace_missing_info(data_df = data)
```

Input data file:

```
Old Info,New Info,Secondary Replacement Info
Carl,Carl,Carl
,Diana,Diana
Jeremy,Jeremy,Jeremy
,,Jack
```

ETA: note that I read in the blank entries as NA's so you can use R's nice NA handling system, via the na.strings = "" argument. This could be adjusted if your input data is different.

Second edit (per comment): If you want to access columns by names instead of column number, you can use the following code for the function and function call instead:

```
replace_missing_info <- function(data_df, column_with_blanks, 
    primary_replacement_column, secondary_replacement_column){

    for(i in 1:nrow(data_df)){
        print(i)
        if(is.na(data_df[i, column_with_blanks])){
            if(!is.na(data_df[i, primary_replacement_column])){
                data_df[i, column_with_blanks] = data_df[i, primary_replacement_column]
            } else if(!is.na(data_df[i, secondary_replacement_column])){
                data_df[i, column_with_blanks] = data_df[i, secondary_replacement_column]
            }
        }
    }

    return(data_df)

}

updated_data = replace_missing_info(data_df = data, "Old.Info", "New.Info", "Secondary.Replacement.Info")
```

Comment: I would use this, but I'll be performing this on 7 separate files which have about 10000-30000 entries each, so if there's a way to do this without using a loop that would be best. Basically I'm using R instead of Excel to avoid the issue of taking large periods of time to process functions.

Comment: This will almost certainly be faster than excel.

Comment: Ok actually this is almost exactly what I was looking for. Definitely admiring your use of na.strings, very handy. How would I make it so that the user can input the text names of columns rather than the columns' index numbers into the function? It's possible to do that but much less efficient on the user's end.

Comment: Insert them via stdin (i.e. command line arguments) or write them in the file?

Comment: Couldn't they be arguments for the defined function? As in, make the function as

replace_missing_info <- function(data_df, columnwithblanks, primaryreplacementcolumn, secondaryreplacementcolumn)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79569/discussion-between-xxxrxxx-and-andy-mckenzie).